# How can 2 lines are skew in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry

So the two lines in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ can be written as:
$$d_1: \begin{cases} u_0x_0+u_1x_1+u_2x_2+u_3x_3=0 \\ u'_0x_0+u'_1x_1+u'_2x_2+u'_3x_3=0. \end{cases}
$$
$$
d_2: \begin{cases} v_0x_0+v_1x_1+v_2x_2+v_3x_3=0 \\ v'_0x_0+v'_1x_1+v'_2x_2+v'_3x_3=0. \end{cases}
$$
So I think these lines will be skew if the set of equations will have no solution. That means the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
u_0 & u_1 & u_2 & u_3\\
u'_0 & u'_1 & u'_2 & u'_3\\
v_0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\
v'_0 & v'_1 & v'_2 & v'_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
has the smaller rank than the augmented matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    u_0 & u_1 & u_2 & u_3 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    u'_0 & u'_1 & u'_2 & u'_3 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    v_0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 &\bigm| & 0 \\
v'_0 & v'_1 & v'_2 & v'_3 &\bigm| & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which I find is never the case since the last collumn is only zero? I'm so confused right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two lines are skew if the system of equations has no solutions *in projective space*. Recall that $(0:0:0:0)$ is not a point in projective space.

Passing to the underlying vector space; any two planes will intersect in the point $0$. So the lines are skew if the underlying planes intersect *only* at $0$.

Comment: sorry my mistake. It's $\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Then my second point still holds, and perhaps my bonus question isn't as interesting.

Comment: so the set of equations has (0:0:0:0) as the only solution. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Well, in the underlying vector space the system has only the solution $(0,0,0,0)$. In the projective space the system has no solution. There is no such thing as $(0:0:0:0)$ in projective space.